# Robust to/ against

Tags: word-usage, expressions, prepositions, synonyms

Which preposition should be used with '*robust*'?
I want to say e.g.:

> This material is robust against/to (??) environmental influence.

Is there, if robust is not the right word in this context, an alternative to say that (e.g. stable (to/against)?)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the sample sentence is non-idiomatic. Materials are not normally said to be robust; and *robust* doesn't collocate with *influence*.

Comment: @PhilSweet I did not know that. Indeed, there are several languages where the word _robust_ has this meaning in conjunction with a certain preposition.

Comment: As far as innate properties go - resistant to, impervious to, or unsuseptable to. If this is an engineered material, you could have *hardened against, protected against*, etc. But I would use "*withstands* environmental influence".

Comment: Assuming this is related to engineering, `durable` would be the more common word choice. For example, `"..is highly durable and resistant to the elements"`.

Comment: @LukeBriggs I just wrote a minimal example. It is referring to engineering, but rather to mathematical engineering. ``The value A changes barely when value B changes`` - so it is robust. But here is my preposition problem.

Comment: @black Right ok; in which case it would depend on surrounding context, i.e. if this is part of a conclusion then rephrasing into something of the form `is weakly affected by external factors/ environmental influence and is therefore robust` may be more suitable.

Comment: Otherwise if used the other way around (such as in your question) then you might result in a kind of `"the red car is red"` phrase - it being unaffected by environmental influence is *possibly* implied by your use of robust anyway, depending on context of course.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do not recall ever seeing ***robust*** used in quite that way, and a quick search through the many different senses of the word in the OED did not reveal any use of *robust* with a preposition.

The word, originating from the French *robuste* has been around in English since at least the fourteenth century. But a few recent examples quoted of its use when speaking of material objects are as follows;

> 1882   Macmillan's Mag. Apr. 430/2   The room in which they found
>   themselves, though clean, and neatly furnished with robust oaken
>   furniture, bore symptoms of unwonted disorder.
>
> 1946   V. N. Wood Metall. Materials i. 36 (heading)    The whole is
>   encased in a robust steel shell.
>
> 1961   P. J. Bhatt Fund. Servo Control Engin. 58   Magnetic amplifiers
>   and transducers are static robust units which can be conveniently
>   mounted (e.g., astride the driving motor).
>
> 1988   Jrnl. Navigation 41 330   The compass..was a simple, robust
>   instrument with a large steering prism.
>
> 2007   Trail Feb. 76/3   This robust accessory keeps my four
>   mugs-worth of water piping for nine hours.

The point is that robust is not a word which conveys much other than strength. What you need to do is to express in what sense it is strong against environmental influences. This could be; *this material is robustly resistant to environmental influences*, but it could equally well be that *this material is robustly enhancing of environmental influences* - perhaps a trifle unlikely, but I feel sure that examples could be conjured where the word *robust* could act as a qualifier for two entirely opposite reasons.

**The point I am making is that *robust against*, without a further adjective is a rather limp expression**.

Comment: There is always tomorrow, Mari-Lou. Happy Christmas xx

Comment: I will return! Merry Christmas WS2

Comment: When an adjective is used to modify a noun, a preposition is impossible in any circumstance. The OP is using 'robust' not as a noun modifier but as a predicate. In a predicate like "The system is robust ____ failure of 2 out of three air conditioning units".

Comment: @Mitch What is that saying? Do you mean *the system is  operationally robust following failure of 2 of the 3 air conditioning units*?

Comment: @WS2 The underscore is where the expected preposition goes. The OP is asking which preposition, 'to' or 'against'.

Comment: @Mitch I did realise that. But *robust to failure* and *robust against failure*, whilst comprehensible, are not idioms I would use, and not ones that one often hears.

Answer (score 8):

A great resource open to you for looking at the frequency of words or phrases is **[Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/)**.
[This Ngrams analysis](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=robust+to%2Crobust+against&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Crobust%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Brobust%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BRobust%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crobust%20against%3B%2Cc0) answers the question quite well:

[image]

Comment: You forgot [Robusto](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/2303/robusto)